# How to put twitter widget script to script file

Tags: widget, twitter

I have created twitter search widget.

```
 <script>
           new TWTR.Widget({
               version: 2,
               type: 'search',
               search: 'TulaDev',
               interval: 10000,
               title: '',
               subject: '',
               width: 295,
               height: 297,
               theme: {
                   shell: {
                       background: '#ffffff',
                       color: '#ffffff'
                   },
                   tweets: {
                       background: '#ffffff',
                       color: '#444444',
                       links: '#1985b5'
                   }
               },
               features: {
                   scrollbar: false,
                   loop: true,
                   live: true,
                   behavior: 'default'
               }
           }).render().start();           
        </script>
```

When I put it to separate .js file it does not work. Is it possible to put it to separate file and set div element where script has to show widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>`

to the separate file along with what you have.